# equation from the static points

Tags: polynomials

The following is from the maths higher 2014 paper[image]

I got answer C which was wrong.

My workings are:

${k(0 + 1)(0 -2) = -8}$

${-2k = -8}$

${k = 4}$

${y = 4(x + 1)(x -2)}$

Which is answer C but the correct answer is B.

I don't understand how my answer is wrong.

Comment: You're assuming that your curve is defined via the polynomial $k(x-a)(x-b)$ of degree 2, while the curve on the picture is definitely not a parabola.

Comment: Read your notes on the roots of polynomials, especially if they mention multiple roots. No calculation is needed to do this question.

Answer (score 4):

A can not be since for $x=0$ we get $y=-4$
D can not be since for $x=0$ we get $y=-32$
C can not be since $y'=4(x-2)+4(x+1)$ and for $x=2$ we get $y'(2)=12 \ne 0$
B can be (control it!)